# Unreal Engine 4: How to load map with different game mode?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

We have two maps:

Map 1: Title Menu - Uses a custom game mode with the HUD for handling Options, etc and no spawn

Map 2: Actual Main Level - Uses the default Third Person Game Mode

When we run both maps in editor, they work great, but when we try to go from one to the other using Blueprint, the scene is messed up and lighting needs to be rebuilt. We are assuming it's because of the different game modes between the two.

How should we go about handling this? We can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

Figured I'd post the solution in case someone else runs into this problem.

The problem we had was we were using the blueprint node 'Load Level' which loads the second map into the first map. This is obviously not what we were trying to do.

Instead, we should have been using 'Open Map' which loads the second map. The map will load with the GameMode intended in that case.